# Adding classes to raster visualization using QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, visualisation

This is my first time working with rasters in QGIS. I'm working with a single band gray raster.
It has 5 classes. When I open it in QGIS, I can see the gray scale for the 5 classes. However, in the layers panel I can only see 2 classes, which are the 2 extremes (white and black).

How can I visualize all 5 classes in the layers panel?

Answer (score 2):

Try "Paletted/Unique values" and color ramp "Greys" under symbology tab:

[image]